# Laravel Nova Editing Relationship within pivot data

Tags: laravel-nova, laravel-relations

I have 3 tables using the same pivot table.  I am trying to be able to edit the value in Nova, but it seems to be completely ignoring the field.

An Employee can work for multiple Companies, and will have a Title and Role specific to that company. So the title and role are kept as pivot data.

```
-- employees
    - id
    - name

-- companies
    - id
    - name

-- roles
    - id
    - name

-- company_employee
    - id
    - company_id
    - employee_id
    - title
    - role_id
```

```
employee belongsToMany company
employee belongsToMany role
company belongsToMany role
role belongsToMany company
role belongsToMany employee
```

```
class Employee

public function companies(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Company::class, 'company_employee')
        ->withPivot(['id', 'title', 'role_id']);
}

public function roles(): BelongsToMany
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'company_employee', 'employee_id', 'role_id', 'id', 'id')
    ->withPivot(['id', 'title', 'role_id']);
}
```

```
Class Company

public function roles(): BelongsToMany
{
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'company_employee', 'company_id', 'role_id', 'id', 'id')
            ->withPivot(['id', 'title', 'role_id']);
}
```

```
Class Role

public function companies(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Company::class, 'company_employee', 'role_id', 'company_id', 'id', 'id')
            ->withPivot(['id', 'title', 'role_id']));
}

public function employees(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Employee::class, 'company_employee', 'role_id', 'employee_id', 'id', 'id')
            ->withPivot(['id', 'title', 'role_id']));
}
```

In Nova for the employee resource I have:

```
BelongsToMany::make('Companies', 'companies')
    ->fields(new CompanyEmployeeFields())
    ->searchable(),
```

In CompanyEmployeeFields I have:

```
return [
    Text::make('Title', 'title')->nullable(),
    BelongsToMany::make('Role', 'roles', Role::class),
];
```

I see Company and Title when creating/editing the resource, but Role doesn't even show up or throw any errors in the logs.

Does anyone have an idea what might be going on?